# It is safe to use Windows Authentication in an internal-only Blazor app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, windows-authentication

I'm wrapping up development of a Blazor application and I wanted to make sure there are no issues handling authentication and authorization the way I am.

The app is only accessible to internal company users using a jump server. Each user's jump server identity has a special group attached to their account that allows them access to the Blazor app.

Since the app is internal only and is only accessed by AD users using browsers that support Windows auth, I have added Windows auth to the API only by adding the Authorize attribute to the controllers like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows", Policy = "MyCustomPolicy")]
[ApiController]
public class ExampleTestController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

In my `Startup.cs`, I've added a policy that looks for the appropriate security role like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("MyADRoleId"));
});
```

This works great. If the user doesn't have the role it returns a 403 and the client app shows the user a Not Authorized screen. My question is, are there any security vulnerabilities created by handling authorization in this way?

Comment: As long as there are no flaws in your authorization implementation, you will be fine. Because of the `AuthorizeAttribute` attached to your controller, a user will only be able to access it if the Bearer (assuming you use JWT) passes the policy. You should do more research into ASP.NET Core Identity, Authentication and Authorization.